# Problem with using spring and tiles in intellij

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tiles-3

I tried many things what I can search in google. but failed to solve this.
If I use only 'InternalResourceViewResolver' it works.
but if use tiles, it dosen't work at all.
help me please.

spring : 5.3.15
tiles : 3.0.8
tomcat : 9.0.54
SDK : OpenJDK 17

error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContex
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.request.ApplicationContext
```

POM.xml :

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tiles/tiles-jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<bean name="/index" class="com.fonad.web.controller.IndexController" />
<bean name="/notice/list" class="com.fonad.web.controller.notice.ListController" />
<bean name="/notice/detail" class="com.fonad.web.controller.notice.DetailController" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/" location="/*"></mvc:resources>
```

tiles.xml :

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="notice.*" template="/WEB-INF/view/customer/inc/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Notice" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/view/inc/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="visual" value="/WEB-INF/view/customer/inc/visual.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="aside" value="/WEB-INF/view/customer/inc/aside.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/view/notice/{1}.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/view/inc/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

controller class :

```
public class ListController implements Controller {
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("notice.list");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

}

web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

solved.

project structure -> artifact -> add tiles and jstl libraries to WEB-INF/lib